# Reaching back out to PIs of interest to inquire about PhD application status

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, etiquette

I'm a senior undergraduate student awaiting (physics) PhD program application decisions. I spent a chunk of last summer writing to and, occasionally, informally interviewing with PIs of interest, and I ended up applying to about 18 programs. I unfortunately have not yet heard positively from any of them, and people around me are starting to suggest that this is bad news at this point in the cycle.

I understand that some of my peers have had success reaching back out to PIs of interest whom they had previously written to or spoken with to inquire about their application status (one, for instance, wrote late last night and as a result received an informal acceptance this morning). There are three or four schools, and five or six specific PIs that I am *particularly* interested in working with, and to whom I have previously written  (all responded with some variation of "yes, I am taking students this cycle and encourage you to apply"). I'm considering writing them again to ask whether they have identified students of interest, and whether I can reasonably expect that there remains some chance I could be admitted this late in the cycle.

**Would it be advisable to do so?** I can imagine arguments for and against. It might show initiative, and/or remind them of my interest and existence. I know that PIs typically do not make final admissions decisions, but they often play a significant role in who does or does not make the cut. On the other hand, one could imagine that it might be seen as an annoyance. I know that professors have a lot on their plate— particularly those serving on admissions committees —and are perhaps receiving a significant amount of email from other prospective students.

It is incredibly important to me that I am admitted to a graduate program, and I'm trying to do whatever I can to make that happen. I love conducting research, am convinced that this is what I want to do with my life, and recognize that being able to do so in the subfield(s) I am most interested in and at the level I would like to is highly contingent upon receiving a PhD.

Comment: In the programs you applied to, do they admit students to an overall program or to specific professors? If it's a program-based admission, then even if you've indicated interest in working with specific professors, those professors aren't the ones admitting you.

Comment: @BryanKrause As I understand it, all admit students to the overall program, not to specific advisors. At at least one, however, I'm told that advisors are asked to select their top choices (sufficient to fill however many positions they have "open"), and this is then taken into consideration when making admissions decisions (although it is not the final word).

Answer (score 3):

They're not going to make admissions decisions based on who asked or didn't ask about their application, they're going to make admissions decisions based on who they think is fit best to get a PhD in their program among the applications they receive. There isn't any cost or benefit to asking with respect to admissions.

Probably a better target for your inquiry is the graduate program rather than individual professors. It's not the role of the individual professors to communicate admissions decisions. I'm not sure how much value there is in asking, though, either: once decisions are made, they'll communicate them. Until you've heard positively and accepted an offer, you should be considering other plans for next year anyways.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be advisable to do so?

You can always ask! I do not think it is likely it will affect the outcome for you one way or the other, but it is possible. At the very least, it should give you some additional clarity on whether your application is seriously being considered.

> I can imagine arguments for and against. It might show initiative, and/or remind them of my interest and existence.

Yes, this is correct. Many professors may not keep a careful log of students who have reached out to them and/or applications to their group, so it is possible that they will see your email and reconsider whether they want to take you.

> I know that PIs typically do not make final admissions decisions, but they often play a significant role in who does or does not make the cut.

This depends very much on the university and program. For example, in my university, it is solely the PI's decision to admit individual students in their group, with essentially no input from a general admissions committee.

> On the other hand, one could imagine that it might be seen as an annoyance.

Also correct, but there are ways to reduce the chances of this. I recommend keeping your email brief. If you are polite and do not sounding demanding (you are just letting them know that you are still interested), it is unlikely it will be misinterpreted.

> It is incredibly important to me that I am admitted to a graduate program, and I'm trying to do whatever I can to make that happen.

I applaud your enthusiasm and I encourage you to not lose hope. If you do not hear back this year even from your "safety" schools, you may want to reconsider your application and experience, it is possible you need to do a bit more work on building your resume before re-applying in the future.

> all responded with some variation of "yes, I am taking students this cycle and encourage you to apply"

Finally, this is overall a good sign! As many professors get too many emails and would not respond at all.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score -3):

In the highly competitive and intense process of PhD program applications, especially within fields as demanding as physics, it's understandable to feel anxious when you haven't heard back from programs as quickly as you'd hoped. However, it’s essential to recognize that the admissions cycle can vary greatly between different institutions and even from year to year within the same program. Thus, not having heard back yet does not inherently signal bad news.

Reaching out to PIs you’ve previously contacted can be a double-edged sword. On the one hand, it demonstrates your continued interest and initiative, which can be favorable if done with tact and consideration for the professors' time and commitments. On the other hand, there's indeed a risk of coming across as overbearing, especially considering the high volume of inquiries PIs and admissions committees receive during this period. It might be beneficial to craft a polite and concise follow-up email, confirming your interest and briefly restating how you believe your goals align with their research, without pressuring for a direct admission status update.

This approach respects the process and the professors' time while keeping the lines of communication open and reminding them of your application.